# Vue JS prop error for value on radio button with v-model and v-bind="$attrs"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting some strange behaviour that I cannot wrap my head around.

I have a simple radio button component that's used as a "wrapper" for an actual radio button.

On this component, I have `inheritAttrs: false` and use `v-bind="$attrs"` on the element itself so I can use v-model and value etc.

However, upon selecting a radio button, an error is thrown that the prop value is invalid (because it's an event and not a string) and interestingly I noticed that on initial render the value prop is blank in Vue Devtools.

I'm simply trying to get these radio buttons updating the parent's data object value for `location` with a string value of the radio button selected.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here exactly. Any help greatly appreciated.

**Example project of the problem:**
https://codesandbox.io/embed/m40y6y10mx

**FormMain.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Location: {{ location }}</p>
    <form-radio
      id="location-chicago"
      v-model="location"
      value="Chicago"
      name="location"
      label="Chicago"
      @change="changed"
    />
    <form-radio
      id="location-london"
      v-model="location"
      value="London"
      name="location"
      label="London"
      @change="changed"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormRadio from "./FormRadio.vue";

export default {
  name: "FormMain",
  components: {
    FormRadio
  },
  data() {
    return {
      location: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changed(e) {
      console.log("Change handler says...");
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**FormRadio.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label :for="id">
      {{ label }}
      <input
        :id="id"
        type="radio"
        :value="value"
        v-on="listeners"
        v-bind="$attrs"
      >
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FormRadio",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        change: event => {
          console.log("Change event says...");
          console.log(event.target.value);
          this.$emit("change", event.target.value);
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's odd that you're setting both `v-model` and `value` - `v-model` should be the source of truth for the value

Comment: But then how would I specify that each radio button has its own value to set? How else would you do that?

Comment: Gonna build an example answer...

Comment: Thank you. If you could utilise the Codesandbox that would be great.

Comment: It's a bit confusing how you're trying to use the same `v-model` on 2 different elements, since it would dictate the value for both elements

Comment: @Lewis No this is correct as it is. It allows you to attach attributes on the wrapper and apply it somewhere else within the component. Normally they default to the top element of the component otherwise. In this case, I am adding attributes to the component that are then passed to the radio button directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Found [this](https://dev.to/vue-storefront/vue-during-coffee-break-using-v-model-with-custom-components-3bo9) neat article which describes the `model` property of a component. Basically it allows you to customise how `v-model` works. Using this, `FormMain.vue` would not have to change. Simply remove the value prop from `FormRadio` and add the model property with your own definition

See updated [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlr1qpm3n6):

**FormRadio Script**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "FormRadio",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  // customize the event/prop pair accepted by v-model
  model: {
    prop: "radioModel",
    event: "radio-select"
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        change: event => {
          console.log("Change event says...");
          console.log(event.target.value);
          // emit the custom event to update the v-model value
          this.$emit("radio-select", event.target.value);
          // the change event that the parent was listening for
          this.$emit("change", event.target.value);
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

**Before Edit:**

Vue seems to ignore the `value` binding attribute if `v-model` is present. I got around this by using a custom attribute for the value like `radio-value`.

**FormMain.vue**

```
<form-radio
  id="location-chicago"
  v-model="location"
  radio-value="Chicago"
  name="location"
  label="Chicago"
  @change="changed"
/>
<form-radio
  id="location-london"
  v-model="location"
  radio-value="London"
  name="location"
  label="London"
  @change="changed"
/>
```

The `input` event handler will update the v-model.

**FormRadio.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label :for="(id) ? `field-${id}` : false">
      {{ label }}
      <input
        :id="`field-${id}`"
        type="radio"
        :value="radioValue"
        v-on="listeners"
        v-bind="$attrs"
      >
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FormRadio",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    radioValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        input: event => {
          console.log("input event says...");
          console.log(event.target.value);
          this.$emit("input", event.target.value);
        },
        change: event => {
          console.log("Change event says...");
          console.log(event.target.value);
          this.$emit("change", event.target.value);
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

See [forked codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqzq4j7pwl)

Comment: I see. Thank you this works. Is this a bug with Vue I guess?

Comment: I think it is by design. It has been reported on components wrapping other native input types. I found this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7526) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

I removed the v-model entirely from the child component call (this was conflicting);

```
<form-radio
  id="location-chicago"
  value="Chicago"
  name="location"
  label="Chicago"
  @change="changed"
/>
<form-radio
  id="location-london"
  value="London"
  name="location"
  label="London"
  @change="changed"
/>
```

I then updated your changed method to include to set the location variable

```
methods: {
  changed(e) {
    console.log("Change handler says...");
    console.log(e);
    this.location = e;
  }
}
```

Updated: Link to updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wo436wmvr8)

Comment: So I guess you're saying to do this manually? v-model should be working...it works with single text inputs this way. It even works if I do not use wrapper components for the radio buttons and simply have them at the top level with the same attributes. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Possibly. I don’t know enough about this to be fair. I can’t show you the working solution as I can’t figure out how to fork your example, I can only suggest you try the edits above and see if it makes any more sense to you than it does to me.

Comment: This technically works...but we lose the benefit of v-model doing this for us. I guess I wanted to avoid the manual sync of properties in data.

Comment: I suppose if `location` is set to "Chicago", using your method, how would you prevent this from applying to "London" as well? I guess this circles back to what @DerekPollard was saying